# Core Data: Is it safer to pass around objects or object ID's?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to work out which is safer/best practice. I have a method that takes an object, gets some data, and saves it to that object. Should I pass that method the object or just the object ID and then re-fetch the object in the method? Is one better than the other or does it not make a difference?

e.g.

```
- (void)getNameFromWebForPerson:(Person *)p {
    //start nsoperation
    operationComplete(NSString *name){
        p.name = name
        [p save];
    }
}
```

or

```
- (void)getNameFromWebForPerson:(ObjectID *)oid {
    //start nsoperation
    operationComplete(NSString *name){
        Person *p = [fetchObjectForID:oid];
        p.name = name
        [p save];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on which thread you are running in the `save` method. The `NSManagedObjectContext` instance that you create to manage these objects should always be accessed from the same thread/queue. It is recommended that if you need/want to use multiple queues to manage objects that you pass the ObjectID around and query like you do in your second example.

See [NSManagedObject's section on Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-SW39)

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like it's best for me to pass the ObjectID.